# Adding a driver from a p5p package during Solaris 11.4 installation

Tags: installation, solaris, drivers, solaris-11

I'm trying to install Solaris x86 11.4 on a machine that requires an additional driver to access its drives. The driver is provided in a p5p-package and I have tried adding the driver before starting the installation using `ddu-text`.

This does not work so far. I tried several parameter-combinations in `ddu-text` and then went on to debug ddu itself. It seems like the initialization of IPS on the installer live-image fails. When `/usr/lib/install/live_img_pkg5_prep` is called, it fails with the following error:

```
builtin: rm: not found
builtin: mv: not found
mv: cannot rename /var/pkg to /var/pkg.1226: Device busy
/usr/lib/install/live_img_pkg5_prep: error moving /var/pkg to tmpfs timesystem
```

I don't believe this simply broken, so what am I doing wrong?